# how to fix /avoid getting null pointer exception when getting a blank cell from method

Tags: java, excel

I try to access a blank cell from method that getting a data from excel sheet.
how can I fix or avoid NPE.

eg.

```
//TestData.java
public static float getData(int sheet, int row, int cell) {

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new String(excelpath));
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

XSSFWorkbook wb = workbook.getSheetAt(sheet).getRow(row).getCell(cell);

...
//blah blah code

if (cell == null) //tried this one but still getting error
  throw new IOException("blank cell ");
...
}
```

in different file I tried to access blank data

```
public void getBlankData(){
float data = (float) testData.getData(99,99,99);
System.out.print(data);
}
```

here is error I hot
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Float.floatValue()" because the return value of "TestData.getData(int, int, int)" is null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If a value can be `null`, you must test it before using it.  `if( value != null ) { use(value); } else { bail(); }`

Answer (score 0):

When getting a blank cell with the workbook class like you are in this scenario, that cell is assigned a null value by default which is why you are getting a NPE. Try using the setMissingCellPolicy(Row.MissingCellPolicy missingCellPolicy) method to initialize empty cells as something other than null. I found this method in the Workbook POI API online.